# Redirect all URLS to new URL EXCEPT for /backend/ with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, exception, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect all incoming queries to a new domain, except for /backend

I have this in my .htaccess, everything works, except for the /backend. I tried a few combinations, it just doesnt work.

I fear /backend is a virtual address....

what can i do?

HERE IS THE CODE:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.de$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.de$

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/backend/$
 
RewriteRule (.*)$ https://www.bing.de/ [R=302,L]
```

PLEASE HELP. Thank you. Patrick

Comment: What do you mean by "virtual address"?

Comment: Is the URL you want to implement an exception for _really_ exactly `/backend/`? Because that is what you test for. Not `/backend` or `/backend/something`. But _exactly_ `/backend/`?

Comment: It is exactly /backend/. But the directory does not exist. Therefore it must be some kind of a virtual address.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "virtual address". The http server is not interested in the physical file system at that stage of processing. It only operates on a string base. Only later, when all redirtions, rewritings and mappings are done, only then the server side file system is considered. Long story short: whether a folder with that name exists is totally irrelevant here.

Comment: I suggest you enable rewrite logging. It allows you to understand on a step by step base what is actually going on inside your rewriting engine. See the documentation on how to enable that.

Answer (score 0):

> I fear /backend is a virtual address....

In which case you most probably have other mod_rewrite directives that rewrite the request to a front-controller (such as `index.php`) - and that's the problem. Whilst your existing rule includes an exception for `/backend/` (the originally requested URL), so the rule is skipped on the first pass by the rewrite engine, once the request is rewritten to the front-controller (eg. `index.php`) the rewrite engine begins a 2nd pass which results in the rule being successfully executed since the URL is now `/index.php` (or whatever your front-controller is) and not `/backend/`.

You either need to:

- modify the other directives that rewrite the request to the front-controller, so as not to trigger a 2nd pass through the rewrite engine. (You've not included your complete `.htaccess` file, so I'll discount this approach for now.)
- OR, make sure you only examine the originally requested URL and not the rewritten URL. (The `REQUEST_URI` server variable is modified as the request is rewritten.)

However, I would assume that your `/backend/` page also links to static assets (such as images, CSS, JS)? In which case, you also need to make exceptions for any additional static assets that are used by the page, otherwise these will also be redirected. For the sake of this example, I will assume all you static assets are located in an `/assets` subdirectory.

Try the following instead, near the top of your root `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.de [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/backend/\s
RewriteRule !^assets/ https://www.bing.de/ [R=302,L]
```

Note that this rule must go before the rewrite to the front-controller.

The `THE_REQUEST` server variable contains the first line of the HTTP request headers and importantly, does not change as the request is rewritten. This contains a string of the form `GET /backend/ HTTP/1.1` (containing the request *method*, *URL* and *protocol*).

If there are no external assets then change the `RewriteRule` *pattern* from `!^assets/` to simply `^`, to match everything.

Comment: PERFECT! This one works, with a slight modification.

Comment: @Patrick That's great. If this helped answer your question then please mark it as "accepted" by clicking the tick/checkmark next to the answer on the left below the voting arrows (to help other users and remove the question from the unanswered question queue). You can also upvote answers you find helpful. Thanks, much appreciated. :)

Comment: @Patrick What was the "slight modification" that was required?