# Excluding a Specific Page during URL Redirection in .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect, litespeed

I'm trying to redirect all URLs from an old domain to a new one, except for two specific pages. I have implemented the following code in the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?olddomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/contact-form [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/about [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Although the redirection works correctly for all URLs, the excluded pages (contact-form and about) on the old domain become unavailable, resulting in a 404 error from the server:

```
404
Not Found
The resource requested could not be found on this server!
```

I'm unsure why these excluded pages are experiencing the 404 error. Any help in resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated."

**Update:**

To troubleshoot the problem, I switched to a staging environment on my localhost (XAMPP with **Apache** server). Initially, I left the default Wordpress codes in the .htaccess file (between "# BEGIN WordPress" and "# END WordPress") intact:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /wp/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wp/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Then, I modified the above-mentioned code to the following one to ensure that all the static resources, including images and css/js files, needed to load the /contact-form and /about pages will be available and added it before "# BEGIN WordPress":

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?localhost/wp$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(contact-form|about)($|/) - [L]

# Exclude specific file extensions from redirection
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/contact-form/?\s [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|js|png|jpg|gif|webp|ico)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/about/?\s [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|js|png|jpg|gif|webp|ico)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The result was successful as all URLs of localhost/wp were redirected to their corresponding ones on example.com, except for the excluded pages (/contact-form and /about).

However, when I tested the same .htaccess file on a live website (LiteSpeed server), I encountered the 404 server error again when visiting /contact-form and /about.

Therefore, it seems that the problem lies in the **LiteSpeed** server configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the source website is WordPress then I would expect these "excluded URLs" to be redirected to `/index.php` (or whatever the source website's front-controller is) on the "new domain" - which is then presumably triggering the 404?

The reason being is that whilst you are excluding these URLs on the initial request, the WordPress code block then rewrites the request to `/index.php`, which then triggers a second pass by the rewrite engine. During the second pass, the URL-path is now `/index.php` (which is *not* `/contact-form` or `/about`) so then triggers the redirect.

You need to make sure your redirect rule only applies to the initial request and not the rewritten request by the WordPress code block. You can do this by checking against the `REDIRECT_STATUS` environment variable.

**UPDATE:** You also need to make sure that any static assets/scripts that these two pages require are not also redirected.

For example:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|js|png|jpg|gif|webp|ico)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/contact-form [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/about [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The check against the `REDIRECT_STATUS` env var ensures that only direct requests from the client are tested and not internally rewritten requests. `REDIRECT_STATUS` is empty on the initial request and "200" (as in 200 OK HTTP status) after the first successful rewrite.

I've left the `NC` flags in place, however, I would expect only `/contact-form` (all lowercase) would be a successful request on the old domain?

Are the old and new domains pointing to the same place? I assume not, otherwise you would need additional rules to separate the two sites (although maybe that is also a problem?). If not, then the check against `HTTP_HOST` is not required.

See also [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73608934/369434) to the following related question: [Exclude folder in domain redirection in .htaccess using WordPress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73606683/exclude-folder-in-domain-redirection-in-htaccess-using-wordpress) and also [Redirect all URLS to new URL EXCEPT for /backend/ with .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73351888/redirect-all-urls-to-new-url-except-for-backend-with-htaccess)

Comment: Thanks @mrwhite. The source website is Wordpress, but the excluded URLs aren't redirected anywhere, instead, I simply receive a 404 server error when visiting them

On my localhost (XAMPP, Apache server) I left the default WP htaccess codes between "# BEGIN WordPress" and "# END WordPress" intact. 

Then modified the above-mentioned code to the following one to ensure that all the resources needed, including imgs and css/js files, to load the /contact-form & /about pages will be available and then added it before # BEGIN WordPress:

Comment: ```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?localhost/wp$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(contact-form|about)($|/) - [L]

# Exclude specific file extensions from redirection
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/contact-form/?\s [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|js|png|jpg|gif|webp|ico)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/about/?\s [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|js|png|jpg|gif|webp|ico)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: The result was successful as all URLs of localhost/wp were redirected to their corresponding ones on example.com, except for the excluded pages.

However, when I tested the same .htaccess file on a live website (LiteSpeed server), I encountered the 404 server error again when visiting /contact-form and /about.

Therefore, it seems that the problem lies in the LiteSpeed server configuration. Do you have any idea on how to resolve this?

Comment: @VandaNojan-وندانوژن Please update your question with your complete `.htaccess` file. (Code blocks in comments are difficult to read.) Yes, you will also need to make an exception for any static assets/scrips that your two pages need on the old domain (sorry, I overlooked that in my answer).

Comment: Thanks, I just updated the question and provided you with the complete htaccess file. hope it helps.

Comment: @VandaNojan-وندانوژن You need the original WordPress code block (between the `# BEGIN WordPress` and `# END WordPress` comment markers), otherwise you will certainly get a 404. The redirect rule in my answer should then go at the top of the `.htaccess` file, before the `# BEGIN WordPress` comment marker.

Comment: of course, the .htaccess file consists of both code blocks. but when I tested your code, in which `RewriteEngine On` had been replaced with `RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$` the `olddomain.com/contact-form` got redirected to `newdomain.com/contact-from`

Comment: I re-tested your code block, and interestingly, while `olddomain.com/contact-form` got redirected to the new domain, the same did not happen to `olddomain.com/about`. This gave me a clue that the problem apparently had something to do with the hyphen in `contact-form`. So, by removing the `-`, I changed the URL to `olddomain.com/contactform` temporarily (and modified the code accordingly). The problem got solved in this case, and the page did not get redirected.

Comment: @VandaNojan-وندانوژن The hyphen should not make any difference at all. Is it possible that `contact-form` also exists as a physical directory or file of the form `contact-form.<ext>` (where `<ext>` could be any file extension)?

Comment: No, it does not exist as a physical directory or file named, for example, "contact-form.html", "contact-form.php", etc. It is simply a page, just like /about, created by Wordpress

Comment: For testing purposes, I created a new page called "/about-us" and it did not experience any redirection issues. Therefore, it proves that your code is functioning correctly. I sincerely appreciate all the assistance you have provided.